# Can ISP know whether port forwarding is been done?

Tags: isp, port-forwarding

I sit behind a NAT of an institute, which has a rule that implies that no port forwarding can be done.

I am developing a peer to peer application, which I need to test. So I have to be sure that it doesn't land me into some problem.

What I have tried and know about:

- I know about `UDP` and `TCP` hole punching, but it requires an external(port-forwarded) server which again is the same problem.

  - I have read about `UPNP` and `STUN` protocols, but It's beyond me.

What I want to know is, does the ISP of my institute know about that port forwarding is been done and who is doing it?

Comment: Whoever controls the WAN device, controls the NAT/Port Forwarding. Can you tell me more about the rule that implies that no port forwarding can be done?

Comment: The institute has specifically said that the internal Computers or any device cannot host or act as a server.

Answer (score 1):

If your institute's policy is that no port forwarding can be done you need to accept this. The correct way is to talk to your boss/IT support/whoever responsible about this problem and that you can't do your job. If you try to circumvent policy your job might be in danger.

The institute's ISP is not the issue, the policy is.

Port forwarding necessarily involves the NAT router. If you've got no control over it this is one more reason to go the offical way (it also makes this question off-topic here). UPnP and STUN are not likely to work in your scenario (unless someone seriously botched the router setup).

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the company asks the ISP itself to perform the redirection of doors when it sees that its client does not have technically qualified people. In this case, you need to know if the person who manages the equipment that does the NAT (radio ubiquiti in cases that the ISP provides link through it or the equipment of the operator that is in its structure (CPE) is its management or both
  (your institute and ISP) to make the necessary changes.